# Error importing xlsx into sas creates trailing 9's

Tags: excel, import, sas, importerror, datastep

I have an Excel xlsx file with many worksheets, so I used an macro to import into SAS.

```
%macro import (outname,sheetname);
proc import datafile="C:\testing.xlsx" 
out= &outname
dbms=xlsx replace;
sheet="&sheetname";
run;
proc contents data=&outname varnum;
run;
%mend;
```

However, for some of the values with decimals, it creates a very weird trailing 9's. For example, the original xlsx viewed in Excel it reads 3.2, it would show up as 3.19999999999999 in SAS dataset. This does not happen for all values with decimals, only sporadically and it's really annoying. Anyone had this experience before? Greatly appreciate some help.
I'm using SAS 9.3.

Comment: floating point problem, probably. 3.2 cannot be represented exactly, and literally is 3.19999... internally.

Comment: Try `dbms=excel`, that might work better for this particular issue.  Also check that Excel isn't hiding the same issue (with a number format)...

Comment: I did try dbms=excel - didn't make a difference; and it's not a problem with number formatting in Excel (it shows as '3.2' in the formular bar as well). I don't understand why is there floating point when the excel entry was just 3.2?

Comment: Can you create a new spreadsheet, enter 3.2 in the formula bar, and verify that this issue still happens?

Comment: I had major frustrations with this and there is no _one size fits all_ sollution for it, so before I can help you I must know **1. Do you have control over the spreadsheet?** Do you create it, do users fill in a template you supply or do you have to do with what they deliver? **2. Why is it annoying in your case?** What do you want to do with this data: display it in a graph?

Comment: please, give a try with excel engine libname or exporting this file in another format such as .csv

Comment: @DirkHorsten 1) File was exported from some Oracle database and given to me, but had all numerically values stored as text. So I converted them back to numbers in Excel then import into SAS. 2) I know it won't affect anything, but I just like have things neat and tidy, can't stand the sight of these weird anomalies >.< Anyways, I saved the file in .xls (older version of Excel) and it seemed to have solved the problem. But still curious why it did happen...

Comment: And if you import the original `.xlsx`, what does SAS read? Strings with digits?

Comment: If you change convert the digits exported by Oracle to numbers, you do a *first conversion*. If you then import the Excel numbers to SAS Numeric columns, you do *again a conversion*. If you import the string of digits as strings, though it is strictly spoken a conversion from variable length strings to fixed length string, it does not bring any conversion risk (as Oracle does not export numbers with more than 250 digits :). Then you can write a `data step` with `input` statements to convert them to numbers